# Virtual Assistant Skill - how to kill/end the current skills bot you are in

Tags: c#, botframework

I was trying to implement an msbot skill that handles the directory services, such as the contact number and email of a person. My issue is I cannot get out of the skills bot. I have tried everything but nothing works.

I am trying to do the following on the skills bot to end or kill it, and return the dialog state to the parent:

- EndDialogAsync()
- CancelAllDialogsAsync()
- EndComponentAsync()

but unfortunately I am not able to return to the parent bot, instead it keeps comming back to the skills bot, and its not what I wanted. I maybe doing it wrong, I am not sure how to end the skills bot state and return to the parent bot, as the main functions are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an `EndOfConversation` Activity. See how our [skills sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot) [does it](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot/EchoSkillBot/Bots/EchoBot.cs#L19):

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Contains("end") || turnContext.Activity.Text.Contains("stop"))
    {
        // Send End of conversation at the end.
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"ending conversation from the skill..."), cancellationToken);
        var endOfConversation = Activity.CreateEndOfConversationActivity();
        endOfConversation.Code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully;
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(endOfConversation, cancellationToken);
    }
[...]
```